# edge to edge html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video, fullscreen

I'm running an HTML5 video on my page and I'd like to make it resize edge to edge in ratio based on the browser's size. It will be set as a background with very little on the page.

To cover my ass, I'm using VideoJS to play the video and handle backwards compatibility. The fullscreen function built into the library works well, but is triggering the browser's native fullscreen function. In some browsers this means black bars, in Safari it means literally fullscreen independent of the browser window. I don't want either of these.

http://videojs.com/

Ideally, it would function like Supersized does for images. The image is always set to the full width of the page, and height is cropped towards the CENTER from there. As you resize the page smaller and smaller, it hits a min-height and begins cropping the width towards the center.

http://lara.fm/

My JavaScript knowledge is minimal, but I'm able to poke and prod to figure things out. I figured that dropping in the Supersized resizing scripts after the VideoJS library and forcing them to work on `video` tags would work in some way.. at least a starting place, but it didn't work.

Can someone help me understand what function can adjust width to the page, height in ratio, and crop towards the center at a certain width or height? Here's what I've got so far:

http://kzmnt.com/test/

This is a tuffie, I know. Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, (based on the demo you posted)

```
.video-js-box.fullScreen{
    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
}
.fullScreen .video-js{
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

add the class .fullScreen at the video-js-box and see what happens.

I am trying to achieve the effect you described above, and I 'll let you know as soon as I find a better solution.

EDIT: Ok I think I found a solution - (VERSION 2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title>HTML5 Video Player</title> 

  <!-- Include the VideoJS Library --> 
  <script src="http://kzmnt.com/test/video.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady();
  </script> 

  <!-- Include the VideoJS Stylesheet --> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://videojs.com/video-js/video-js.css?v=1292015834" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Video JS"> 
  <style>
  body{margin:0;}
.video-js-box.fullScreen{
    width: 100% !important;
    min-width: 380px !important;
    min-height: 280px !important;
    position: relative;
    background: #eeeeee;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100% !important;
    z-index:998;
}
.fullScreen .video-js{

    height:auto;
    /*height: 100% !important;
    width:100% !important;*/
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.video-js-box{
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
}
.video-js-box video{
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
} 

#buttonImportant{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:8px;
    background:#eeeeee;
    font-size:1.3em;
    z-index:999;
}
  </style>
</head> 
<body> 

 <div id="buttonImportant"> CLICK ME!!!  </div>



  <div class="video-js-box" id="videoContainer"> 
    <video class="video-js" preload loop fullscreen autoplay> 

      <source src="http://kzmnt.com/test/vid/kozmonaut_by_christina_tan.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' /> 
      <source src="http://kzmnt.com/test/vid/kozmonaut_by_christina_tan.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' /> 
      <source src="http://kzmnt.com/test/vid/kozmonaut_by_christina_tan.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' /> 
      <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="1280" height="720" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"> 
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" /> 
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" 
          value='config={"playlist":["http://kzmnt.com/test/vid/kozmonaut_by_christina_tan.png", {"url": "../vid/kozmonaut_by_christina_tan.mp4","autoPlay":true,"autoBuffering":true}]}' /> 
      </object> 
    </video> 
  </div> 


 <script type="text/javascript">

var clicked =  document.getElementById("buttonImportant")

var videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer');
var video = videoContainer.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

video.style.height="auto";
video.style.width="400px";

clicked.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if( videoContainer.className.lastIndexOf("fullScreen")>=0 ){
        videoContainer.className="video-js-box";
        video.style.height = "";
        video.style.width="";
    }
    else
    {
        videoContainer.className="video-js-box fullScreen";
        video.style.height = "";
        video.style.width="";
    }
    myResizerObject.prevWidth = video.offsetWidth;
    myResizerObject.prevHeight = video.offsetHeight;



    myResizerObject.Init();
},false);

    var RESIZER = function(){ 

        this.prevWidth = video.offsetWidth;
        this.prevHeight = video.offsetHeight;

        this.videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer');
        this.video = videoContainer.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        this.videoStyle = this.video.style;

        var ratio = this.video.offsetHeight/this.video.offsetWidth;

        var that = this;

        this.Init = function(){
            if( that.videoContainer.className.lastIndexOf("fullScreen")>=0 )
            {
                var videoContOffsetWidth = that.videoContainer.offsetWidth;
                var videoOffsetWidth = that.video.offsetWidth;
                var videoContOffsetHeight = that.videoContainer.offsetHeight;
                var videoOffsetHeight = that.video.offsetHeight;

                if(that.prevWidth!= videoContOffsetWidth)
                {
                    that.prevWidth = videoContOffsetWidth;
                    var desired = videoContainer.offsetHeight/videoContainer.offsetWidth;
                    if(desired>ratio){
                        that.videoStyle.width=videoContOffsetWidth*desired+videoContOffsetWidth*desired+"px";
                        that.videoStyle.left = -1*(videoOffsetWidth-videoContOffsetWidth)/2+'px';
                    }
                    else{ 
                     that.videoStyle.cssText="height:auto;width:100%;left:0px;top:0px;";
                    }
                }

                if(that.prevHeight!=videoContOffsetHeight)
                { 
                    that.prevHeight = videoContOffsetHeight;
                    var desired = videoContOffsetHeight/videoContOffsetWidth;  
                    if(desired>ratio){  console.log(ratio);
                        that.videoStyle.top = '0px';
                        that.videoStyle.left = -1*(videoOffsetWidth-videoContOffsetWidth)/2+'px';
                        that.videoStyle.width = videoContOffsetHeight*desired+videoContOffsetHeight/desired+'px';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        that.videoStyle.top = -1*(videoOffsetHeight-videoContOffsetHeight)/2+'px';

                    }
                }

            }
        };
    };

    var myResizerObject = new RESIZER();
    window.onresize = myResizerObject.Init;

 </script>

 </body> 
</html>
```

Copy - paste the above code to a new file and test it : )

MAJOR EDIT 2:  I refactored my code, and packaged it in a more object oriented form. Now it does move (modified top and left css attributes) so that the video remains centered when the screen ratio changes. It still does a weird little jump but it works quite well. 
I will keep working on this task because I think it's a cool feature. Also I have no idea what happens or what would you like to happen during the flash fallback.

ps. I kept the click me button but it is very easy to disable it.

Comment: @Pantelis - didn't quite work the way I was hoping. Here's what I'm thinking.. center the object dynamically with javascript to accomodate for varying size... set width of the video to 100%. theoretically sound.. right??

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. Please check again, (tested it in Chrome and ie9)

Comment: @Pantelis. Wow. just.. wow! You're a king amongst kings. two thoughts: 1) triggering the fullscreen on page load instead of having to click the button 2) horizontal crop towards center instead of top left (solved by dynamically centering the video?? see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379979/center-object-with-variable-width-using-jquery

Comment: Hey, you're welcome! Sorry for taking so long to reply (had to get some sleep), I edited the above code so that it is in "prettier" form, and made it center when the ratio change!

Comment: Wowwiee.. Native Javascript is definitely beyond me.. Again, thank you so much. The video (while resized) doesn't center on the page.. still locks up off the top left corner.. Did it work for you?

Comment: Good news.. Was able to stack in my jQuery function for centering an object on load and when the window is resized. when firing your JavaScript from the button the video resizes, but is offset (because of my centering function. resize your window fires mine and then boom! it's edge to edge and centered!!!!!!!!!

That said, I still need your help :) I'm not sure how to translate my jQuery function into native JavaScript and then combine it with yours so that resizer(); resizes and centers the video. also, not sure how to do it on load instead of click. Hope this isn't too much. you RULE.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're question has been answered, more or less, but for others looking for a quick and dirty way to handle this, I just pulled apart "jQuery Easy Background Resize Plug-In" and made it work for video. Pretty easy.

Html looks like this:

```
<div id="video-container">
  <video autoplay="autoplay" id="video">
    <source src="/videos/11280741.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Javascript looks like this (look towards the bottom for the video specific stuff)

```
/******************************************************
    * jQuery plug-in
    * Easy Background Image Resizer
    * Developed by J.P. Given (http://johnpatrickgiven.com)
    * Useage: anyone so long as credit is left alone
******************************************************/

(function($) {
    // Global Namespace
    var jqez = {};

    // Define the plugin
    $.fn.ezBgResize = function(options) {

        // Set global to obj passed
        jqez = options;

        // If img option is string convert to array.
        // This is in preparation for accepting an slideshow of images.
        if (!$.isArray(jqez.img)) {
            var tmp_img = jqez.img;
            jqez.img = [tmp_img]
        }

        $("<img/>").attr("src", jqez.img).load(function() {
            jqez.width = this.width;
            jqez.height = this.height;

            // Create a unique div container
            $("section#content").append('<div id="jq_ez_bg"></div>');

            // Add the image to it.
            $("#jq_ez_bg").html('<img src="' + jqez.img[0] + '" width="' + jqez.width + '" height="' + jqez.height + '" border="0">');

            // First position object
            $("#jq_ez_bg").css("visibility","hidden");

            // Overflow set to hidden so scroll bars don't mess up image size.
            $("body").css({
                "overflow":"hidden"
            });

            resizeImage();
        });
    };

    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
        resizeImage();
    });

    // Actual resize function
    function resizeImage() {

        $("#jq_ez_bg").css({
            "position":"fixed",
            "top":"0px",
            "left":"0px",
            "z-index":"-1",
            "overflow":"hidden",
            "width":$(window).width() + "px",
            "height":$(window).height() + "px",
            "opacity" : jqez.opacity
        });

        // Image relative to its container
        $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css("position", "relative");

        // Resize the img object to the proper ratio of the window.
        var iw = $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').width();
        var ih = $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').height();

        if ($(window).width() > $(window).height()) {
            //console.log(iw, ih);
            if (iw > ih) {
                var fRatio = iw/ih;
                $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css("width",$(window).width() + "px");
                $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css("height",Math.round($(window).width() * (1/fRatio)));

                var newIh = Math.round($(window).width() * (1/fRatio));

                if(newIh < $(window).height()) {
                    var fRatio = ih/iw;
                    $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css("height",$(window).height());
                    $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css("width",Math.round($(window).height() * (1/fRatio)));
                }
            } else {
                var fRatio = ih/iw;
                $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css("height",$(window).height());
                $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css("width",Math.round($(window).height() * (1/fRatio)));
            }
        } else {
            var fRatio = ih/iw;
            $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css("height",$(window).height());
            $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css("width",Math.round($(window).height() * (1/fRatio)));
        }

        // Center the image
        if (typeof(jqez.center) == 'undefined' || jqez.center) {
            if ($("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').width() > $(window).width()) {
                var this_left = ($("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').width() - $(window).width()) / 2;
                $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css({
                    "top"  : 0,
                    "left" : -this_left
                });
            }
            if ($("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').height() > $(window).height()) {
                var this_height = ($("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').height() - $(window).height()) / 2;
                $("#jq_ez_bg").children('img').css({
                    "left" : 0,
                    "top" : -this_height
                });
            }
        }

        $("#jq_ez_bg").css({
            "visibility" : "visible"
        });

        // Allow scrolling again
        $("body").css({
            "overflow":"auto"
        });

        $("#video-container").css({
            "position":"fixed",
            "top":"0px",
            "left":"0px",
            "z-index":"-1",
            "overflow":"hidden",
            "width":$(window).width() + "px",
            "height":$(window).height() + "px",
            "opacity" : jqez.opacity
        });

        $("#video-container").children('video').css("position", "relative");

        var iw = $("#video-container").children('video').width();
        var ih = $("#video-container").children('video').height();

        if ($(window).width() > $(window).height()) {
            //console.log(iw, ih);
            if (iw > ih) {
                var fRatio = iw/ih;
                $("#video-container").children('video').css("width",$(window).width() + "px");
                $("#video-container").children('video').css("height",Math.round($(window).width() * (1/fRatio)));

                var newIh = Math.round($(window).width() * (1/fRatio));

                if(newIh < $(window).height()) {
                    var fRatio = ih/iw;
                    $("#video-container").children('video').css("height",$(window).height());
                    $("#video-container").children('video').css("width",Math.round($(window).height() * (1/fRatio)));
                }
            } else {
                var fRatio = ih/iw;
                $("#video-container").children('video').css("height",$(window).height());
                $("#video-container").children('video').css("width",Math.round($(window).height() * (1/fRatio)));
            }
        } else {
            var fRatio = ih/iw;
            $("#video-container").children('video').css("height",$(window).height());
            $("#video-container").children('video').css("width",Math.round($(window).height() * (1/fRatio)));
        }

        // Center the image
        if (typeof(jqez.center) == 'undefined' || jqez.center) {
            if ($("#video-container").children('video').width() > $(window).width()) {
                var this_left = ($("#video-container").children('video').width() - $(window).width()) / 2;
                $("#video-container").children('video').css({
                    "top"  : 0,
                    "left" : -this_left
                });
            }
            if ($("#video-container").children('video').height() > $(window).height()) {
                var this_height = ($("#video-container").children('video').height() - $(window).height()) / 2;
                $("#video-container").children('video').css({
                    "left" : 0,
                    "top" : -this_height
                });
            }
        }

        $("#video-container").css({
            "visibility" : "visible"
        });


    }
})(jQuery);
```