# center object with variable width using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, window, center

Need to center an object whose width changes depending on the browser window. Usually I'd use css with top and left positions set to 50% with a negative margin equal to half the width and height, but obviously that wouldn't accomodate this need.

I thought my jQuery function would work... but no bueno. am i missing something in CSS?

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/EbkLg/2/

Here's the CSS

```
#t {
        width:25%;
        height:25%; 
        background:red;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     resizenow();
});
function resizenow() {
    var browserwidth = $(window).width();
    var browserheight = $(window).height();
    $('#t').css('left', (browserwidth - $(this).width())/2).css('top', (browserheight - $(this).height())/2);
});
```

Comment: Is your code something that's getting called on the windows resize() event? Or are you just trying to statically set the position of the object once using javascript?

Comment: oooh.. window resize. completely slipped my mind.

Comment: Adjusted my approach. Updated here and on jsFiddle

Comment: Two problems:  You are getting a pixel value from `width()` and you're expecting it to be percent.  Then you are putting a number into `css()` without specifying any units ('px' or '%').  See my updated answer below.

Comment: width() returns a unitless value @Sparky672 - it's different from what gets returned from .css(width) Additionally, you don't need to specify units for setting css('top', foo) - it defaults to px for you.

Comment: @kinakuta- exactly as I stated in my answer below... it's a unitless value but **it's still a PIXEL value**.  You too should read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/) where it states: _"unit-less PIXEL value"_.  Defaulting to pixels is fine but the OP is claiming to use only percentages.

Comment: That's just because the style above was edited to use percentages. It was originally pixels. And I don't need to read the docs, so I'm not sure why you're suggesting I should.

Comment: @kinakuta:  You stated, `width()` _"returns a unitless value"_ ... however, according to the docs, it's returning a _"unit-less PIXEL value"_ just as I had originally stated... A pixel value (but without the 'px')

Comment: @kinakuta:  Your answer deserves the checkmark for being more complete than mine.  However, I do not think the OP understands that the width(), height(), css() and calculations are all being performed with the pixel values (unit-less) and not percent.

Comment: I get that part. I thought at first you were saying width() returned the value as having "px" on it, as if it had to be parsed out. I see re-reading your comment that's not what you said. Regardless, I understand how width works - my comment was in the context of the original post which styled the object with static pixel values.

Comment: @kinakuta:  I see.  Yes you do, and I did not realize that `css()` would default to using 'px' when no units are specified.  However, when I started adding 'px' within the `css()` in the original fiddle, I was able to get it working for some reason.  And the OP's comment on my answer below was so baffling, it sent me up here to make these quick comments.  ;)

Comment: Yeah, I think a lot of confusion was injected when it was changed from the original 500px width and height values to the 25% values which I didn't even notice until long after.

Comment: @kinakuta:  And when I came into it, it was already 25%... lol  Anyway, +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSFiddle that you linked to you use `$(this).width()`:

```
$('#t').css('left', ((browserwidth - $(this).width())/2))
.css('top', ((browserheight - $(this).height())/2));
```

But when the function resizenow() is called, `this == window`. If you replace `$(this)` with `$("#t")` it works fine, as this JSFiddle shows: http://jsfiddle.net/jackfranklin/F2tR3/1/

Within the `css()` function of jQuery, the value of `this` is not set to the element whose style(s) you are changing, hence why your original code didn't work.

Comment: This is why my version worked and I didn't even realize it at first - +1

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  

var browserwidth = $(window).width();
var browserheight = $(window).height();
var x=browserwidth/4;
$('#t').css({'left': (browserwidth - x)/2 + 'px', 'top': (browserheight - x)/2  + 'px'});

$(window).resize(function(){

  var browserwidth = $(window).width();
  var x=browserwidth/4;
  var browserheight = $(window).height();

   $('#t').css({'width' : x, 'height' : x,  'left': (browserwidth - x)/2 + 'px', 'top': (browserheight - x)/2  + 'px'});
   });


#t {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
    background:red;
 }


               });
```

Or if you don't want it to be a square, just don't set width and height in jquery, use percentage in css.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `width()` and `height()` returns a unit-less **pixel** value according to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

But when you plug it back into a calculation for jQuery's `css()`, you need to add the units label "px".

---

**EDIT:**

If your calculation is based on percentages, then everything is wrong since `width()` and `height()` are pixel values.  Either way, you still need to add units, either 'px' or '%' within jQuery's `css()`.

---

**EDIT2:**

`css()` apparently defaults to using pixels but if the OP is using percentages, then `'%'` would be required.

Comment: Nothing's dealing with pixels.. css can handle percents.

Comment: @technopeasant:  You need to read the jQuery documentation.  [See this.](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 1):

It's the way value is getting parsed for the left and top values you're trying to set. If you break them out like this, it works:

```
var widthDelta = $(window).width() - $('#t').width();
var heightDelta = $(window).height() - $('#t').height();
$('#t').css('left', widthDelta / 2).css('top', heightDelta / 2);
```

I haven't analyzed exactly what was going wrong - I just looked for something that worked first - I'll have to look at it closer to see what the problem specifically was.

Comment: works, but not under my window resize function. I'd like it to constantly center itself, even while the browser is resized.http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/EbkLg/11/

Answer (score 0):

This will horizontally center the red div, and it's width and height will dinamically change according to the browser windows size;

```
<div style="position:absolute;display:block;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;">
<div style="width:25%;height:25%;background:red;display:block;margin:auto;"></div>
</div>
```

Now the vertical centering is a bit more complex story...

Answer (score -1):

Try adding position:fixed to your CSS. This will mean that any positioning that you specify for the element will be in regards to the actual window instead of the document.

Not sure if this will fix it but it should.